# Realm not called in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I have a realmService singleton that's using the following code. However it's not been called from the homeController when I request it.

```
var realmService = RealmService.shared.realm

class RealmService {

static let shared = RealmService()

lazy var realm: Realm = {
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
    print("Realm set up")
    return realm
}()

lazy private var realmURL: URL = {
    let appDir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let url = appDir.appendingPathComponent("TEST.realm")
    return url
}()

lazy private var config: Realm.Configuration = {
    return Realm.Configuration(
        fileURL: self.realmURL,
        inMemoryIdentifier: nil,
        syncConfiguration: nil,
        encryptionKey: nil,
        readOnly: false,
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: nil,
        deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false,
        objectTypes: nil
    )
}()
}
```

I get no print statements when a model calls this method like:

```
    print("Calling realm service")
    if let profile = realmService.objects(Profile.self).filter(predicate).last {}
```

Not sure if something is missing?

Thanks!

EDIT: Removed external methods and extension calls to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you set `objectTypes` to `nil`, so no model classes are added to your Realm. You should simply leave that input argument out, which will result in the default value being used and hence all `Object` subclasses declared in your project will be added to your config.

You actually shouldn't be passing in `nil` to any input arguments, which you don't want to assign a specific value to, you should rather leave out those input arguments and let them take their default values.

```
return Realm.Configuration(
    fileURL: self.realmURL,
    readOnly: false,
    schemaVersion: 1,
    deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
)
```